# Double cover of the real projective plane $\mathbb RP^2$

Tags: general-topology, geometry

We know that the double cover of the real projective plane is a sphere $S^2$. How can we visualize this? I am thinking of consider the cross cap model of the projective plane. So start by drawing the cross cap and then take a tubular neighbourhood of the cross cap, the boundary of the neighbourhood is $S^2$. This is my construction, any other idea.

Comment: There is no better visualization than the standard one.

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict the covering $S^2\to RP^2$ to a covering of the Mobius band inside $RP^2$, i.e. $S^2 \supset S^1\times [0,1] \to M\subset RP^2$.

This gives you a way of visualizing what is happening. Since you get $RP^2$ by gluing a disk to the boundary of the Mobius band (which is connected) you can cover the Mobius band with $S^1 \times [0,1] \to M$ and then you glue *two* disks to the disconnected boundary of the product $S^1 \times [0,1]$.